# How to coordinate BackboneJs views and pass objects between them?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, web-applications

#### I have a BackboneJs application and here is the file structure of it.

```
|-- collections
|   |-- customers.js
...

|-- models
|   |-- customer.js
...

|-- views
|   |-- customer
|   |   |-- create.js
|   |   |-- edit.js
|   |   |-- list.js
...


|-- templates
|   |-- customers
|   |   |-- create.html
|   |   |-- edit.html
|   |   |-- list.html
...
```

#### Working code flow

In the `initialize` function of `views/customer/list` view, a customers collection (`collections/customers`) is fetched by `this.collection.fetch`. When render completed after fetching the customers collection from the server, I have a list of customers displayed in html table.

When a user clicks the 'Edit' button in the table's row an event is triggered. The purpose of the event is to load `customer/edit` view so that the user can update the selected customer from the table.

This is done via `Backbone.history.navigate('#customers' + customerId, {trigger:true})`. Then a route took place and `/api/customers/{customerId}` gets called.

#### Summary

There is no problem with this structure, it works as expected. But I think there is no need to go to the server to get customer's details because the `collection` in the `views/customers/list` has the whole customer object. And I can get the selected one as follows 
`var selectedCustomer = this.collection.get(selectedCustomerId)`

#### The Question

My question is how can I pass the `selectedCustomer` object to the `views/edit` view and eliminate the server call for getting the customer's details. Additionally, the hash should change as `#customers/{customerId}` when `views/customer/edit` view is loaded.

Comment: A little bit of code would be helpful.  Is the listView calling the editView, or is there some master file calling them both?  What is your main entry point?

Comment: @Morslamina list view just navigates to `‘customers/{customerId}’` then the application’s `router` calls the appropriate function and edit view is loaded ( `new EditView` ). Edit view gets the data from the server with passed customer id in its initialize function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd consider changing your application flow. Instead of fetching your collection from your `listView`, fetch it from your router and pass it to your `listView`.  Then when your router calls your `editView`, you can pass the collection to `editView` as well, without having to fetch it again.  Then it's just a matter of calling `this.collection.get(selectedCustomerId)` from your `editView`.  Hopefully that answers your question, but without a better look at your code, I can't be much more helpful.

Comment: Definitely agree.  Generally a View that fetches its own data is going to be hard to manage.  Prefer to instead pass data into the view(s) `initialize(...)` method, and then re-use the data for other views that might need them.

Comment: @PeterWagener, both of you are right. But there is one problem about this approach. The application router becomes too complex. I think a Contoller module should be used.